# Modifying output of dtypes

Tags: python

Currently, `dataframe.dtypes` outputs:

```
age        int64
gender     object
date       datetime64[ns]
time       datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

I want the output to only have date and time columns, or conversely, only the columns with type datetime64[ns], i.e. the output should be:

```
date       datetime64[ns]
time       datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

I tried various methods such as using `dataframe.select_dtypes`, but none of them exactly match the required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may select a subpart of your df, with fewer columns :

```
df[['date', 'time']].dtypes
```

To be more generic and get those with `datetime64` type, do

```
import numpy as np
tt = df.dtypes
print(tt[tt.apply(lambda x: np.issubdtype(x, np.datetime64))]
```